# How can I determine the location of an object for one observer given the location for another?

Tags: radio-telescope, interferometry, radio

I know an object exists at the location of the beam-pointing-center of a radio telescope. I know the elevation/azimuth of the beam pointing center, as well as it’s “location” in galactic coordinates. I want to determine at what elevation/azimuth I’d need to point the beam-pointing-center of radio telescope, on another point on earth, to also “point at” the object. For now, I’ll be doing this with pencil/paper, but it will eventually require an implementation in Rust.

Comment: If you have the galactic coordinates of the object, you don't need the coordinates or the az-el of the first observer.  You can just take the location of the second observer, and convert from galactic l, b coordinates to local azimuth and elevation coordinates (sometimes called alt-az or horizon coordinates) for that location and time.  You might have more luck finding formulae for converting equatorial (RA, Dec) coordinates to alt-az; if that's the case, you could convert Galactic -> equatorial (RA/Dec) -> alt-az.